# How to add jQuery inside a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building some toggle function written only with JS then I wanted to add some jQuery library inside the JS function. (For a slow and smooth scroll)
However I'm not quit sure what would be the best practise to do so.

```
function myFunction1() {

   if (subContent1.style.display === "none") {
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#container1').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
});

   setTimeout(function(){
      subContent1.style.display = "block";
      }, 600);

   } else {
     setTimeout(function(){
       subContent1.style.display = "none";
            }, 600);
        }
    }
```

At the moment I've put

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#container1').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
}
```

right after the if statement but it's not working.
Could anyone let me know what'll be the best way to add jQuery inside JS function?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: remove the `$(document).ready(function(){` that does not work in a function. That is the main jQuery function used to do stuff when the page has loaded

Comment: Also use jQuery when you have it! `if (subContent1.style.display ==='none')` is the same as  `if ($(".subContent1").not(":visible"))` ... assuming  subContent1 is a class

Comment: And use `setTimeout(function(){ $(".subContent1").toggle() },600)`

Comment: `How to add jQuery inside a JavaScript function?` jQuery _is_ written in Javascript. You don't need anything special to write javascript inside a javascript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix DOM and jQuery

Don't use `$(document).ready(function(){` in a function. It is not what it is for

Assuming subContent1 is a class, you can do this - it would have been useful to know where you call myFunction1

```js
function myFunction1() {
  if ($(".subContent1").not(":visible")) {
    $('#container1').animate({ scrollTop: 0  }, 'slow');
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".subContent1").toggle(); // show if hidden, hide if visible
  }, 600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**$(document).ready(function(){}** 

is not required in your case, 
because this method is a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the page's 
Document Object Model (DOM) reload & becomes safe to manipulate.
    


And jQuery is written is JavaScript only, in other words just a shorthand of JavaScript. 
        
   Other code is seems fine in your code.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function myFunction1() {
            if (subContent1.style.display === "none") {
                $('#container1').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    subContent1.style.display = "block";
                }, 600);

            } else {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    subContent1.style.display = "none";
                }, 600);
            }
        }
```